# Some epubs output little square characters "obj" to string, encoding issue?

Tags: java, android, encoding, epub

I'm using epublib library to get text from epubs to a string. It does so by choosing a chapter and getting a stream and converting it to a string. It works with most epubs i've tried, but I had a customer send me some epubs that did not show up properly and instead showed some random characters, like so:

Any ideas on how to remedy the issue?

Not sure how to get encoding, or even set encoding in this library.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I had to open the file in gVim, switch to view in hex, to see what the  squares were. Turns out they were odd formatting characters.

You could have characters in the original EPUB, such as "narrow non-breaking space" or "zero width non-breaking space."

Here is a good [decode](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html) page for whitespace characters that may be the source of your random characters.

Once you ID what the offending character is you can probably do something in Java to remove it. But I can't help there.. I'm not Java fluent.